# Добавление данных в определенную таблицу sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Как мне добавить в нужную мне таблицу данные, никаких ошибок не вылезает. А ещё надо ли писать engine.connect перед каждым взаимодействием с таблицей?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, String, MetaData
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///MYdb.db")
engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()
user = Table(
    "user", metadata,
    Column("Yourname", String()),
    Column("Yoursecondname", String()),
)


ins = user.insert().values(Yourname = 'Misha', Yoursecondname = 'Michalkov')

conn = engine.connect()
r = conn.execute(ins)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `conn.commit()` вас не учили делать при внесении изменений в базу? А насчёт коннекта - это по вкусу. Сильно зависит от сценария использования.

Comment: Ну я читаю документацию SQLAlchemy и пытаюсь разобраться как оно работает, что-то как-то проморгал про conn. commit(). Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Ну, там может быть и автокоммит какой-нибудь включен, но судя по симптомам - вряд ли )  Как общее правило запомните, что читать то данные можно и без знания о транзакциях, но запись обычно идёт транзакциями и их нужно коммитить (либо наоборот откатывать, что и происходит, если не сделать коммит).

Comment: Мда, базы данных ,конечно, это ужас. Сижу вот и пытаюсь разобраться в них  2 день уже, но по ощущениям до нормальных знаний БД как до луны

Comment: Ну тогда начните изучение с каких-то базовых знаний sql, а не разу с библиотек питона

Comment: Ну я и то, и то учу